# About Martingale Stopping Theorem

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, martingales, stochastic-integrals, stopping-times

Prove that:
A right-continuous process $X$ adapted to the filtration $\{\mathcal{F}_t\}$ is a martingale if and only if for any bounded stopping time $T$, $X_T \in L^1$ and $E[X_T] = E[X_0]$.

I know the "only if" part, but how comes the "if" part?

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Converse" of optional stopping theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2223288/converse-of-optional-stopping-theorem)

Comment: You should be able to adapt the proof given there to continuous-time process.

Comment: For given $0\le s<t$ and $A\in\mathcal F_s$, examine the equality $E[X_T]=E[X_0]$ for the stopping time $T:=s$ on $A$; $:=t$ on $A^c$, bearing in mind that $E[X_t]=E[X_0]$ by the stated hypothesis.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, I made it to the continuous time case.